# Trying to make an image into a link in the HTML/JavaScript Gadget in Blogger

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

When I input the following code, in the HTML/JavaScript Gadget, the image takes me to www.healthywholebeautiful.blogspot.com/www.facebook.com/nayda.sadr.

```
a href="www.facebook.com/nayda.sadr" target="_blank"
```

followed by

```
<img src="IMAGE">
```

Am I entering something wrong that is causing it to open up with my blog's domain preceding the Facebook URL?

Comment: is that the actual code? because I don't see a closing </a> and the opening needs <>

Comment: Try using `https://` before the link. (`https://www.facebook.com/nayda.sadr`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `http://` or `https://` in your link, you are missing the protocol.

So it must be,

`<a href="https://www.facebook.com/nayda.sadr" target="_blank">`

Comment: Thank you! I figured it was something small that a beginner like me would be missing!!